# How to set android.app.default_searchable meta data tag in abstract base class activity

Tags: android-actionbar, abstract-class, searchview

i am creating an abstract base class activity for options menu. i am extending my main activity with the base activity. in the manifest file i placed the metadata tag like below

**Manifest:**

```
   <activity
            android:name="com.schoolinsites.mcpss.BaseActivity" >
          <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
        </activity>

   <activity
            android:name="com.schoolinsites.mcpss.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >

        </activity>
```

my main activity is extending from the Base activity .if i search from the mainactivity i am not able go to the search activity but if i place the metadata tag in the Mainactivity i am able to move the search activity. how can i place the meta data tag in the Baseactivity.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible since the BaseActivity isn't launched as a Activity but the MainAcitivty is.